# IPW Weights for Marginal Structural Models for Different Estimands

Tags: panel-data, causality, propensity-scores, treatment-effect, marginal-model

As [Blackwell and Glynn 2018](https://www.mattblackwell.org/files/papers/causal-tscs.pdf) note, an interesting property of marginal structural models is their ability to estimate treatment effects that account for the dynamic properties of panel data. For example, the estimation of unbiased lagged treatment effects, the estimation of the effects of an entire treatment history, etc.

My question is, how would you go about estimating MSMs for each unique treatment effect.

Say that I am interested in estimating the following treatment effects:

- **Contemporaneous treatment effect (CET)**: the effect of treatment in the current time period.
- **1-period lagged treatment effect**: the effect of treatment one period prior in the current time period.
- **The "step-response" function**: the effect of a permanent shift in treatment status in some future outcome.

Both for the estimation of the weights and the specification of the outcome model, where might one find information on how to specify the weights formula/outcome model dependent on their estimand of interest?